# Exposing group information with mod_authnz_ldap

Tags: apache, ldap, kerberos

This page here (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#exposed) says that I should be able to expose information returned by the authldapurl as environment variables which are prefixed with AUTHORZE_. I cannot find any working examples though where someone exposed for example the ldap group information of the current requests user.

I expect that when forging an URL like this ldap://host:port/basedn?attribute?scope?filter that all the listed attributes of the search result will be set as env variables, or am i wrong?

We want to use mod_auth_kerb for authentication and then mod_authnz_ldap for authorisation. Can someone explain what the AuthLDAPUrl has to look like to expose the current users group information?

In a second step we will use the information to set it as headers. In the end what I want to have are 2 request headers, one for the remote user and one for its group memberships.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Please upvote this enhancement request at Apache HTTPD to request this capability for mod_authnz_ldap: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65945

Answer (score 0):

This is my Apache HTTPD config using Kerberos for authentication and LDAP group memberships for authorization:

```
KrbServiceName HTTP/this.isyour.url.tld@REALM.TLD
KrbAuthRealms REALM.TLD
KrbLocalUserMapping On
Krb5Keytab /path/to/keytabs/keytab.file

AuthBasicAuthoritative On
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap.directory.tld/o=BaseDN?uid?sub?(&(cn=*))"
AuthLDAPBindDN "YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HERE"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "YOUR BIND PWD HERE"

AuthLDAPGroupAttribute uniqueMember
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
require ldap-group cn=Website Test,ou=groups,o=BaseDN
```

The schema names are for a pure LDAP server (Oracle Unified Directory, in this instance). Active Directory would require some changes -- uid is sAMAccountName, uniqueMember is just member, and the base DN is probably going to be dc=something,dc=somethingelse instead of o=something.

Comment: This answer only shows how to check group membership. It does not answer the OP question bcos it does not show a AuthLDAPUrl attribute that exposes a user's group memberships. To be fair I don't think any such attribute exists in current versions.